# How to limit users to their home directory SFTP on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, best-practices

Is there any way to limit users to certain home directories with sftp on Ubuntu OS 20.04 and giving them write access to their directory?'

I was able to keep each user to only see their directory and not browse any other directories. However, they can't write to their directory now. Below is the config for /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match User XXXXXXXXX
 
ForceCommand internal-sftp 
 
PasswordAuthentication yes 
 
ChrootDirectory %h 
 
PermitTunnel no 
 
AllowAgentForwarding no 
 
AllowTcpForwarding no 
 
X11Forwarding no
```

Thanks in advance for any help!